# which is the best way to show a status message in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Which is the best way to show a status message in asp.net. For example, after saving data to DB I want to show a message like 'Data Saved Successfully". I would like to know which is the best way to show this kind of status message in asp.net.

Thanks All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the success of your query, in code behind You can just add text to a lable like:

```
Label1.text = "Data Saved Successfully";
```

Don't give and default text to that label in design page.

further more you can give color to that label like :

```
Label1.color = "green";
```

SO that it will look like a Success Message.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the rest of the site/application is written as there are a number of ways:

1) Javascript - A nice message box returned/displayed to the user with the message

2) Pure server side - A returned value to the return page which is displayed in a styled info box

And that's just scratching the surface ...